# probability dice consideration of previous results

Tags: probability, dice

I am looking for a formula to calculate this problem: If you roll a dice n times and you get y times the number one, how is the probability in try 8 in consideration of the prevois results?

Here an example:

```
    |   1   2   3   4   5   6 (dice)
------------------------------------
1   |   -   -   -   -   x   -
2   |   -   -   x   -   -   -
3   |   -   x   -   -   -   -
4   |   x   -   -   -   -   -
5   |   -   -   -   -   -   x
6   |   x   -   -   -   -   -
7   |   -   -   -   x   -   -
8   |   ?
```

`P(AuB) = P(A) + P(B) - P(AnB)` is not correct, or?

Comment: I guess you are trying to do conditional probabilities? If so, can you amend your post accordingly?

Comment: I feel like it's a trick question. The probability of rolling a 1 is 1/6 regardless of previous attempts. If I misunderstand the question please clarify it.

Comment: You say you roll the die $n$ times but then you ask about the probability on roll number $8$. Did you mean to roll the die $7$ times? Did you mean to ask about the probability on roll number $n+1$?

Answer (score 0):

Dice rolls are statistically independent.  "Previous outcomes" are irrelevant when calculating the expected outcomes on roll 8.  Thus the probability of each number appearing on roll 8 is the same, and equal to 1/6.